# LNK1104 : Cannot open file pthreadsVC2.lib

Tags: c++, pthreads

This is the error I get when tying to build a simple code with threads.

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Sample_with_Threads, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  source.cpp
1>c:\users\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\sample_with_threads\source.cpp(39): warning C4715: 'set_cur_avg' : not all control paths return a value
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'pthreadsVC2.lib'
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I use visual C++ and I followed http://web.cs.du.edu/~sturtevant/pthread.html to include pthreads in it.

Why is the error occurring and what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions fully in the link you posted? It says:

- From the lib folder from the download.
- Paste pthreadVC2.lib (Object File Library) to the Visual Studio 2010
  lib folder for C++.

  - On my computer this is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
    Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib.  It will likely be similar or the same on
    other systems.

A bit further down, it also says:

- Go to Common Properties>Linker>Input.
- In Additional Dependencies add pthreadVC2.lib as a dependency.

Comment: Hmm, have you done that for all configurations that you're building, e.g. Debug, Release, etc.? Are you sure the dll and lib files are where they're supposed to be? Sorry, I can't think of why this would not work if you've followed the steps fully.

Comment: ...and also make sure I type "pthreadVC2.lib" and not "pthreadsVC2.lib". A really silly error.

Answer (score 3):

This error is due to file `pthreadsVC2.lib` not being "visible" to linker. Make sure you specify this file in the list of libraries to link to and also (if needed) the path to that file in the project's settings, so that the linker:
1. "knows" that it needs to link this library in and,
2. can find the file

From your question it sounds like you have "included" the pthreads (as in"included a header file"). This is only enough to make your source file compile, but the linker needs to know where to find the symbols that were included in that header file